# Is lambda-calculus without self-application turing complete?

Tags: functional-programming, programming-languages, computation-theory, lambda-calculus

Is lambda-calculus without self-application turing complete? Is there a proof of so?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it belongs on cs.stackexchange.com

Comment: I was not sure if it belonged to cs, theorical cs or here, but I've seem similar, well-accepted questions here (such as [this](http://goo.gl/bXb35k) and [this](http://goo.gl/SpGahu)), so how not?

Comment: Mind explaining what do you mean by "self-application"?

Comment: Applying a term to itself, such as `x x` in `((λx.x x) (λx.x x))`

Comment: How would you go about forbidding self-application?

Comment: @ibid, you might not explicitly forbid it, but self-application is not well-typed, so if you introduce a type system, it is implicitly "forbidden".

Comment: @pash, that depends on how sophisticated the type system is.

Comment: @Ganesh Sittampalam, can you give me an example of a type system in which self-application is well typed?

Comment: GHC Haskell:

`Prelude> :set -XScopedTypeVariables -XRankNTypes`

`Prelude> :t \(f :: forall a . a -> Int) -> f f`

`\(f :: forall a . a -> Int) -> f f :: (forall a. a -> Int) -> Int`